# IMDBPY - how to get the series from an episode?

Tags: series, imdbpy

I have an episode-id and from this I want to derive the series.
How can I do that?

This is what I tried:

```
ia = IMDb()
movie = ia.get_movie(id)
if movie['kind'] == "episode":
    series = movie['episode of']
    print(series)
```

This gives me only the series title, allthough the documentation says, 'episode of' gives in addition the id of the series.

Answer (score 0):

The `series` object stored in the `'episode of'` key is an instance of the `Movie` class, so you can access the series ID using:

```
imdbID = series.movieID
```

You can also update the information of the Movie instance so that more information (besides title and ID) are collected, with something like:

```
ia.update(series)
```